# Show the SubFolders in DIV using Sharepoint REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

I have this code bellow:

```
jQuery.ajax({
                url: "https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/test/Negocio/_api/web/Folders('Historico')/Folders",
                method: "GET",
                headers: {
                    "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" 
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
```

The code returns all subfolders, I want to  insert **for each subfolder** the properties like *title*, *created* in this code:

```
<div id="SubFolders">
    <div>
        <label>SubFolder Title</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Something else...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample code for your reference:

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function getfolders() {
    $.ajax({
            url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/folders('doc1')/folders",
            type: "GET",
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            },        

            success: onQuerySucceeded,
            error: onQueryFailed
        });

    }

    function onQuerySucceeded(data) 
    {
          console.log(data.d.results);
           $.each(data.d.results, function (key, value) {
           $("#SubFolders").append("Folder Name: "+ value.Name+"<br/>");
           $("#SubFolders").append("Folder Created Time: "+value.TimeCreated+"<br/>");


          });
    }

    function onQueryFailed() {
        alert('Sorry An Error Has Occurred!');
    }
     $(function() {
     ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getfolders, "sp.js");

    });

    </script>
<div id="SubFolders">

</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, is giving me *undefined* instead of name and data.

Comment: What  you got from console.log(data.d.results); check the browser Developer Tool by clicking F12